# Laravel Change output of the view in controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I need to change all @ in my parts of static and dynamic in view to [at].
So I have :

```
return view('myview')->with('items',Model::all());
```

When I try this my result is String :

```
return ChangeSymbols(view('myview')->with('items',Model::all()));
```

whats best way to change output of view in controller o any where .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to achieve what you want:

```
$template = view('emails.welcome')->render();

$template = str_replace("@","[at]",$template);

return $template;
```

This is just an example. Note the [render()](https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/View/View.html#method_render) function which returns the string value of compiled view.